# Function to return a part of a list

Tags: function, haskell, syntax

I am new to Haskell and have an assignment. I have to write a

> Int->Int->[u]->[u]

Function that is given input two Ints i and j and a list and returns the elements that are in possitions greater than i and smaller than j. What I have thought so far is:

```
fromTo :: Int->Int->[u]->[u]
fromTo i j (h:t) 
    |i == 1 && j == length(h:t)
        = (h:t)
|i /= 1
    fromTo (i-1) j t
|j /= length(h:t)
    fromTo i j init(h:t)
```

However I get a syntax error for the second |. Also im unsure if my train of thought is correct here. 
(init returns the list without its last element)

EDIT: Corrected

```
|i /= 1
    fromTo (i-1) j (h:t)
```

to

```
|i /= 1
    fromTo (i-1) j t
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed indentation, parenthesization, and missing `=`s. This reformation compiles, and works for ordinals and finite non-empty lists:

```
fromTo :: Int -> Int -> [u] -> [u]
fromTo i j (h : t)
   | i == 1 && j == length (h : t) = h : t
   | i /= 1                        = fromTo (i - 1) j t
   | j /= length (h : t)           = fromTo i j (init (h : t))
```

I think you're looking for something like this pointfree, naturally indexing `span`:

```
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take _ []       = []
take 0 _        = []
take n (x : xs) = x : take (n - 1) xs

drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop _ []       = []
drop 0 xs       = xs
drop n (_ : xs) = drop (n - 1) xs

span :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
span i j  =  drop i . take (j + 1)
```

which

```
span 0 3 [0 .. 10]  ==  [0,1,2,3]
```

Or, to fit the specification:

```
between :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
between i j  =  drop (i + 1) . take j
```

which

```
between 0 3 [0 .. 10]  ==  [1,2]
```

Comment: Well that is a solution, but the point of the assignment is to understand recursion and lists.

Comment: @Stelios The reformatted `fromTo` works for ordinals and finite lists; `fromTo 1 4 [1 .. 100]  ==  [1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: Yes it does indeed, now I am trying to make it work for infinite lists as @ephemient suggested

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `=` between the `|` guard clause and the body. The Haskell compiler thinks the whole thing is the guard, and gets confused when it runs into the next `|` guard because it expects a body first. This will compile (although it is still buggy):

```
fromTo :: Int -> Int -> [u] -> [u]
fromTo i j (h:t) 
  | i == 1 && j == length (h:t) =
    (h:t)
  | i /= 1 =
    fromTo (i-1) j t
  | j /= length (h:t) =
    fromTo i j (init (h:t))
```

but I would say there are better ways of writing this function. For example, in principle a function like this should work on infinite lists, but your use of `length` makes that impossible.

Comment: Indeed. It does not work for infinite lists. How could I implement this though to work for infinite lists without knowing where to stop with j?

Comment: @Stelios The solution @nowhere provides does work on infinite lists. Look into how `drop` and `take` work to understand.

Comment: Yes but as I said, the point of the assignment is to understand recursion and lists. If I use the easy stuff 1) It is not allowed and 2)I actually do want to understand recursion and lists :P

Comment: @Stelios Look at the implementation of `drop` and `take`, which do work on infinite lists by recursion. The base library shipped with GHC is easy browsed online, see [`drop`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#drop) and [`take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#take).

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete solution that use recursion:

```
fromTo :: Int -> Int -> [u] -> [u]
fromTo i j xs = go i j xs []
    where go i j (x:xs) rs
        | i < 0 || j < 0 = []
        | i > length (x:xs) || j > length (x:xs) = []
        | i /= 0                        = go (i - 1) j t
        | j /= 1           = goo i (j -1) (rs ++ [x])
        | otherwise = rs
```

Notes:
`go` is standard Haskell idiom for recursive function that need extra parameters compared to main level function.
First clause make sure that negative indexes result in empty list. Second does the same for any index that exceed size of a list. **Lists must be finite**. Third "forgets" head of the array `i` times. Fourth will accumulate "next" `(j - 1)` heads into `rs`. Fifth clause will be triggered when all indexes are "spent" and `rs` contain result.

You could make it work on infinite lists. Drop second clause. Return `rs` if `xs` is empty before "exhausting" indexes. Then function will take "up to" `(j-1)` elements from `i`.